# css 3d cube has strange space on hover rotate

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have a row of 3d cubes, when you roll over them it rotates (I guess it's technically not a cube, since there are only two sides, but the illusion is it's a cube).  When the cube is not rotated it sits just like it's suppose to, but when you hover and the rotation happens, the green rotated container is offset to the right and I'm not 100% sure why.

Thanks for any help in advance.  Here is the js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/loriensleafs/c3ewZ/1/

the html is as follows:

```
<div class='box-scene'>
    <div class='box'>
        <div class='front face'>
        </div>
        <div class="side face">
            <p>This is back</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='box-scene'>
    <div class='box'>
        <div class='front face'>
        </div>
        <div class="side face">
            <p>This is back</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='box-scene'>
    <div class='box'>
        <div class='front face'>
        </div>
        <div class="side face">
            <p>This is back</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='box-scene'>
    <div class='box'>
        <div class='front face'>
        </div>
        <div class="side face">
            <p>This is back</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:
body {
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }

```
.box-scene {
    -webkit-perspective: 700;
    width: 25%;
    height: 180px;
    float:left;

    z-index: 999;
}
.box-scene:hover .box {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
}
.box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;

    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;

    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 90px 90px -90px;


}

.face {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: visible; 

    -webkit-transform-origin: 0 0;
}
.front {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    z-index: 2;
    background: #d9d9d9;
}
.side {
    background: #9dcc78;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg);
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Comment: It's the first, 3rd and 4th squares that do, the 2nd doesn't, looking into it for ya

Comment: hmmm for me they all do it, I'm almost positive it has to do with     -webkit-transform-origin: 90px 90px -90px; in the .box class.

Comment: originally the .box-scene had a with of 180px, when you change it back to that the rotation actually works fine, so it has to do with that I'm pretty sure.

Comment: No, it has to do with the origin of your rotation. If you look carefully, you will see that the right edge of the green box is the pivot point of the rotation.

Comment: hmmm, any solutions thus far?  Probably going to have to be some JS calculations.

Comment: I've been looking at it for a bit twiddling, but I have found one yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57945/discussion-between-loriensleafs-and-vikingblooded).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the z-axis property in `.box` to `-50%` of the width of `.box-scene`.

The only way to do this seems to be with Javascript, because the browser does not know to what the -50% reference. As pointed out by VikingBlooded the z-axis has to be a length.

```
.box {
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center -50%;
}
```

So since this is not possible and you don't declare a fixed width in your stylesheet, you have to use a script. I don't know if you want to use jQuery, but this little script solves your problem:

```
$(function() {
    var width = parseInt($(".box-scene").css("width"));
    $(".box").css("-webkit-transform-origin", "center center -" + width/2 + "px");
});
```

Comment: "z-offset
Is a <length> (and never a <percentage> which would made the statement invalid) describing how far from the user eye the z=0 origin is set."

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin

Comment: one downside of this: after the page is loaded if you resize the page, it bugs out

Comment: so this didn't for for me.  I tried it and this is what I got: http://jsfiddle.net/loriensleafs/c3ewZ/3/

Comment: actually it works, just remove the window.load wrapper http://jsfiddle.net/c3ewZ/4/

Comment: quick question, on the roll over the text is in reverse, why is that happening?

Comment: You have to add `$(".side").css("-webkit-transform", "rotateY(-90deg) translateX(-" + width + "px)");` in the jQuery section, because you have to rotate it so you still see the front of the `.side`. But this is so to say the wrong direction, so you also have to translate it to the position it should be.